# A partial differentiation question

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

> A function $f : R^n → R$ is called homogeneous of degree D if for
>   every $λ ∈ R$ and $(x_1, . . . , x_n) ∈ R^n $ we have the equality
>   $f(λx_1, λx_2, . . . , λx_n) = λ Df(x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n)$.  Show
>   that any homogeneous differentiable function $f$ of degree $D$
>   satisfies  $\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}
> > = D · f  ∀ (x_1, x_2, . . . , x_3) ∈ R^n.$

How do I do this question. I do not know where to start

Comment: Did you mean $\lambda^D$ rather than $\lambda D$?

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure exactly what you are asking but the following may help you on your way.

Since $f$ is homogeneous of degree $d$, you have $f(\lambda x_1,\dots,\lambda x_n)=\lambda^d f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. Defining $g(\lambda,x_1,\dots,x_n):=f(\lambda x_1,\dots,\lambda x_n)$ you can compute
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial\lambda} = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i},
\end{equation}
or instead writing $g(\lambda,x_1,\dots,x_n)=\lambda^d f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ you can compute
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial \lambda} = d\lambda^{d-1}f(x_1,\dots,x_n).
\end{equation}

These two expressions for $\partial g/\partial\lambda$ may be useful.